# Obtaining conversion data from GA for visits that have triggered some given events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

What I need to do is setup a custom report where I want to know the proportion of conversion rate for people triggering certain events (and certain Labels for these events, as I have a lot of them, a Segment is not really appropriate). I created the custom report with the Conversion rate and Goal Completions as the metrics (in addition to Visits), and for the dimensions I chose all the Events dimensions (eg, Category, Action, Label).

Unfortunately, the report shows 0 conversions. 0 goal completions. This is impossible, eg I can verify via other means that some visitors triggering the events later trigger a goal completion. Is that a bug? It really seems so to me, since with the Ecommerce conversion metrics, everything seems fine...

In addition, googling for that is very hard, because all the information I find is related to "event based goals", which is not at all what I want here. I have a standard URL based goal, and I want to know how many people triggering an event proceded later to complete the goal.

Thanks for any help, this really seems strange to me but I absolutely need to find a way around this problem!

[PS: as a follow-up, I really believe it's a bug in GA. But I'd like confirmation by some other experts.]

Answer (score 0):

Whether the trigger is a pageview or event, establishing a goal is the key (event-based goals are a relatively new feature, but they work pretty much like the pageview goals that have been around for a while).  But I am confused, as it looks like you want the granularity of Events (which allow Category, Action, and Label), but only have a URL -- a goal can be based on one or the other (pageview or Event), but pageviews are not as rich as events ... unless you are able to control your URLs (e.g. /category/action/label/foo.html).

If you have control over the URLs that lead to the goal, (and often even if you don't), if you can determine a pattern that defines the steps that lead to a goal conversion, then you can probably get everything you need, and if multiple steps, even the Goal Completion Funnel.

So the first part is getting the goal working ... and this can be somewhat more confusing than it looks, especially if you need to use regular expressions to define the patterns that do (and do not) match a given goal step.

I highly recommend the Google Analytics Chrome plugin, which lets you trace the data being sent to GA in the developer tools console at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna -- and these days, goals get recorded in a matter of minutes, so you can test them.  I have worked with GA for a long time, and I still find that setting up goals is a trial-and-error process.

Rather than custom reports, I often find that the simple metrics report available on the dashboards provide exactly the data that you need.  Once you see the data correctly filtered and sorted in a report, use the Add to Dashboard, and customize as needed from there.

If you have a specific set of URLs that are part of a goal you want to establish, edit your question to include the examples, and I'll take a shot at helping further.

Comment: Sorry, but you did not understand at all what I need. The goal is properly registered as an URL goal, and it's working (eg, goals completions are registered). But what I want to know is how many people triggering a given event go on to complete a goal. That has nothing to do with setuping an event based goal.
Let's say I have an event tracking links to a video view, I want to know how many people actually bought in my shop after they viewed the video. This is just an example, as what I want to do is actually much more complex and can only be done with events, not virtual pageviews for instance

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.  I was confused by your statement "the information I find is related to "event based goals", which is not at all what I want here. I have a standard URL based goal...".  I am afraid I don't understand still, and think perhaps if you provided an example with sample steps and real or simulated URLs (or event triggers) it would be easier to understand.

Comment: OK, I set it up in my own website as a small example: www.elvanor.net. If you click on my picture, you trigger an event (there is even an alert popping up to tell you). Now I track conversions to www.elvanor.net/resume.php (URL based goal, setup in GA). What I want to know is how many people went to resume.php after triggering the click event (or how many people went to resume.php before triggering the event). Thanks

Comment: I think I understand now.  The goal converts when users view resume.php and you want to know how many of them clicked the picture.  If a goal funnel were possible, this would work -- but goal funnels only work from urls to other urls, not events.  I believe a custom segment is the only solution: of people in the segment <clicked picture> how many visited resume.php?  This also does not tell you whether they clicked first or saw the resume first.  I don't think it's a bug, just a feature that doesn't exist.  I assume you have tried the Visitors Flow report?  This works with segments, though.

Comment: I dont care if they clicked before or after, so this is not really a funnel. I think it's still a bug, because you can create a custom report with Event as the dimension and conversions as the metrics... (note that a custom segment works, but unfortunately in my case, is not feasible for reasons too complex to explain here)